# Confusion on Kirchhoff law of thermal radiation

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation

Reading through the "Radiative Processes in Astrophysics", I came to the part where he discusses blackbody radiation, and among others, states that the specific intensity is a universal function of temperature and frequency:

$I_\nu=B_\nu(T)$

Where $I_\nu$ is the specific intensity and $B_\nu(T)$ is Planck's function.

And then, proceeding to thermal radiation, he somehow concludes that $S_\nu< B_\nu => I_\nu<B_\nu$ and $S_\nu>B_\nu => I_\nu>B_\nu$, and so,  $S_\nu=B_\nu(T)$.

Here $S_\nu=\frac{j_{\nu}}{\alpha_{\nu}} $ is the source function, given as emission coefficient over absorption coefficient.

I don't really understand what's going on here, isn't here $I_\nu=B_\nu(T)$? Why are the above inequalities true?

Comment: Please, notice that we cannot know what you're reading. What is $S$? What is $B$? Please, provide some context. Thank you.